# Error in MediaQuey.removePadding() in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

when I written my code I  get this error in it 'Undefined name 'context'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.'. I tried to fixed by adding 'dart.js' but the error is still. how can I fixed this problem?!
The error is in :
child: MediaQuery.removePadding(
removeTop: true,
context: context, exactly in this line.

```
listServices() {

  return Positioned(
    top: 260,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    child: MediaQuery.removePadding(
      removeTop: true,
      context: context,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 3,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            height: 85,
            width: 340,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(25),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(25),
                ),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Color(0xFFd8dbe0),
                    offset: Offset(1, 0),
                    blurRadius: 10.0,
                    spreadRadius: 10,
                  ),
                ]),
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 18),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 50,
                            width: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(
                                  width: 2,
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 39, 4, 119)),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                image: AssetImage('./images/facture.png'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 10,
                          ),type here
```

I tried to add variable reqiured BuildContext context but it didn't work also.

Comment: Try adding BuildContext as parameter again. -> listServices(BuildContext ctx){...} then inside this method instead of context use ctx. and when you call listServices(context). just pass the context.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap with Padding widget like,

```
Padding(
 padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0)
)
```

Or you can give padding property to your listview also.